# Adding sequential days in ical

Tags: ical

Is there a way to have a running total as an all day event on ical?
Such as "days since last cigarette"?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We'd like to know what research you've already done and what have you already tried to figure this out?  The guidelines in [ask] for asking questions request that you search the site for answers first to show you've taken the time to answer the question yourself.  It also helps prevent us from presenting answers that you've already tried. - From Review.

Comment: I googled the question first and found a thread were someone asked a similar question except they wanted to add to 12 or 26 weeks at the end of each weak.  I tried the AppleScript that was the solution to their question, tweaking it in ways I thought would work for me. but it didn't

Comment: set myCalendar to "jefe"
set myDate to 2 - 4 - 2017
set year of myDate to 2017
set month of myDate to February
set day of myDate to 4

tell application "Calendar"
 repeat with myNumber from 1 to 100
  make new event at the end of events of calendar myCalendar with properties {start date:myDate, summary:"sober " & myNumber, allday event:true}
  set myDate to myDate + (1 * days)
 end repeat
end tell